# Adding a woocommerce bought product function to a plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

So I have this wordpress plugin that by itself hide's the 'add to cart' button and adds a download button when a **Woocommerce product is free**.

But I would like to add another function to this plugin which should do the same when a product has been already purchased.

So I am trying to use the `wc_customer_bought_product( $customer_email, $user_id, $the_product)` woocommerce function.

But it doesn't seem to be working.

```
//Returns true if the product/variation is free, downloadable and vitual.
//Added by me: OR return true too if product was bought

function dfd_is_virtual_free_download_product($post) {

    global $woocommerce, $product;
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $current_user= wp_get_current_user();
    $customer_email = $current_user->email;
    $current_product = $product->id;

    if (empty($post)) return false; 


    $the_product = get_product($post);

    if (!$the_product) {
        //its not a product or product not found
        return false;
    }

    $is_virtual = $the_product->is_virtual();
    $price = $the_product->regular_price;
    $sale_price = $the_product->sale_price;
    $is_downloadable = $the_product->is_downloadable();

    if ($sale_price == "0" || $sale_price == "0.00" ||  wc_customer_bought_product( $customer_email, $user_id, $current_product)){
        $price = $sale_price;
    }
    if($price == 0 && $is_virtual == 1 && $is_downloadable == 1){
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found mistakes in your code.
Why you are gettting ID twice?

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$current_user= wp_get_current_user();
```

$current_user already injected this property, you can call in this way $current_user->ID

Another problem is calling of undefined property $current_user->email

```
//This is wrong
$customer_email = $current_user->email;

//This works
$customer_email = $current_user->user_email;
```

Hope this helps.

Try to call function in this way:

```
wc_customer_bought_product( $customer_email, (int)$user_id, (int)$current_product);
```

You better try to use var_dump() for getting information about values or just debugger.

Comment: Thank you for your hel, but it did not work I'm still getting the same result.